# I'm not able to execute react basic program

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm not able to execute react basic program. localHost is not opening. I have tried creating work space and navigated and created react helloworld folder using npx create-react-app helloworld,the same is created in my work space but while running using  npm start, I'm getting following error in both vs code and cmd [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBeQv.png)md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the WSL path to System32

`export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32`

Comment: Where do I add this " export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32 "

Comment: I have tried adding "C/Windows/System32" in env variable It worked for me thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong command, Use npm run start or npm start

Comment: I ran my react app using npm start, even though it is giving me that error

Comment: https://maximilianschmitt.me/posts/error-spawn-node-enoent-node-js-child-process  Check whether this work for you not